# StackPanel not scrolling in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am building a Custom Control for Windows Phone 8.1. But the stackpanel is not scrolling down. StackPanel contains one ListView which shouws a TextBlock & another StackPanel which houses a Toggle Button.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Background="RoyalBlue">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="Some Text" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>                     
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Toggle Me"  />
            </Grid>
       </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: StackPanel is not scrolling - you should use ScrollViewer. Also you may need to define ListView's height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stackpanel doesn't provide any scrolling.
You can wrap it into a ScrollViewer.

Also: listView already provides Scrolling.

But: The ListView inside stackpanel will pick up all your manipulation events. Also, a ListView inside a Stackpanel will have infinite heigt and therefore loose it's virtualization capabilities.

If you just want to have content above and/below the ListView, maybe use its Header/Footer properties.

Answer (score 1):

Add ScrollViewer over the StackPanel and it will make it scrollable.

**For Example:**

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="12">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="content1" FontSize="48" />
        <TextBlock Text="content1" FontSize="48" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```